# Convenience of inserting external data (products) as Drupal nodes

Tags: commerce

I am building a multisite/multidomain site in Drupal 7. We have a section which will show details of thousand of products of the company and clients. We manage these products with an independent management tool. Is it recommended to insert these products in the database as nodes in order to get full capability of Views listings, search functions, etc.? I was going to use just PHP to manage listing, details page, etc., but I am no sure if keeping them outside of Drupal is a good idea. If it is better to include them as nodes, or any other entity... what contributed modules would be recommended and what would be the best approach? (Import them as csv files in a commerce module, insert them directly in nodes and related tables...).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you have this choices :

1. Use the [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import data to nodes via CSV file, and you can use the powerful [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to list all your product, or develop a simple module that can do that.
2. Use can develop a module that build entities based on your tables, with this approach, you can use your database without creating nodes/terms or other stuffs, but you need to create an admin interface to manage all your tables
3. If you plan to sell your products online, try to use [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), and import with **Feeds module**

Comment: I will try and use Feeds, thanks for your reply. I think that creating nodes with the searchable fields will be the better approach. They will not be editable by any user and controlled only with the external app, but that way I will have all adventages of Drupal: search, friendly urls, taxonomies, Views listing, translation sets, possibility of using commerce, etc., etc.

Comment: Right, by converting to nodes, you will gain all the benefits of Drupal apis, but you must not forget that data must be synchronised with your database, so you must think about an automated solution to import your CSV, a cron maybe?

Comment: Yes. But better than a cron, a listener.php which is activated (with adequate password and port different from :80) from the administrative tool and synchronize all data.

Comment: Yes it can be more effective. I think you know now what you have to do :)